# comparison between pointer and integer warning using #define and argv[]

Tags: c

```
> warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

When I try to compile the following code, I get the above error. I realize this question is commonly asked, and I did find a lot of sources that have helped me, but I wasn't about to find one with #define and argv[]. Apologies if this is a duplicate, nonetheless.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MINBOUND 5
#define MAXBOUND 10

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  if (argc > 1){
    if (MINBOUND <= *argv[1] <= MAXBOUND){
      printf("arg within bound\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("arg outside bound\n");
    }

  else {
    printf("arg missing\n");
  }

return (0);
}
```

Comment: `MINBOUND <= *argv[1] <= MAXBOUND` - where have you seen syntax like that before?

Comment: `else {` -> `}else{`

Comment: Honestly I'm just winging it here. Turns out i'm rustier than I initially thought I'd be

Comment: You're probably going to need `atoi(argv[1])` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: See the program is running fine]

Your code is working fine in my compiler! if it is not then try converting the string i.e argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nVX.png) to integer if you literally want integer comparison.

Actually it's comparing the ASCII value of the first character of argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nVX.png) with MINBOUND only as you can see in the image.
you should do it like

```
> int c=atoi(argv[1]);
>if ((MINBOUND <= c )&&(c<= MAXBOUND))
```

Comment: Moreover, please tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: your edits worked perfectly, thank you!! I'm surprised at myself for not catching the if statement syntax myself tbh

Comment: And here I couldn't understand why my answer is downvoted!!

Comment: yeah idk i'd upvote you but i dont have enough karma sadly. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile right now so I can't test to be certain, but I believe these are your two problems.

1. Pointer to int comparison. Your `#define`'s are defining integers, `*argv[1]` is a char pointer to the string you are passing your program. You need to use `atoi(argv[1])` in your comparison.
2. Your `if` statement syntax is invalid. Break that into two conditions and you `&&` together.